# Can capital gains from employee stock options be transfered to a TFSA to avoid taxes?

Tags: canada, income-tax, tfsa, capital-gain, employee-stock-options

In a scenario where, for example:

An employee exercised a "same-day-buy-and-sell" operation on his employee stock options. He ends up making a profit / gain of $10K. He already has a yearly salary of $55K. Because of this Capital Gain, the employee worries about how much he/she will get taxed and whether or not he will be bumped into a higher tax-bracket.

Just to get some clarity on tax-brackets first:

1. Is it true that only 50% of the Capital Gain is subject to taxes? (ex: %50 of $10K = $5K)
2. How much of that 50% is actually taxed? Does that depend on your current tax-bracket based on just your salary? Or is it ($Salary + 50% of Capital Gain?) = $Amount used to determine which bracket you stand in?

Now, would transferring the Capital Gain (immediately once received) to a TFSA work in the employee's favor in order to cut down on taxes?

- Is it correct to assume that - since a limit of $5K can be stored in a TFSA, the remaining amount (ex: $10K - $5K in TFSA = $5K remaining) would then be subject to the same calculations the full Capital Gain would have undergo? (so %50 of $5K = $2.5K)
- Does the amount tossed in the TFSA have to stay for a certain period of time (days, weeks, months?) before it can be transferred over a standard bank account and/or used to purchase expensive items?

Overall, would there be better alternatives to reduce your tax payout other than reinvesting into more stocks, or mutual funds? How about education? First-time home buyer / mortgage?

***Sorry for the immense question, but this knowledge territory is really blurry for me. Any external resources would be appreciated as well.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to your points #1 and #2:

- In general, yes it is true that *capital gains* are only subject to half one's marginal rate of income tax.  That doesn't mean 50% of the gain is due as tax... rather, it means that if one's marginal tax rate (tax bracket) on the next $10K would have been, say, 32%, then one is taxed on the gain at 16%.  *(The percentages are examples, not factual.)*

  **However, because these are *employee stock options*, the tax treatment is different than for a capital gain!**    Details:

  On the Federal tax return are lines for reporting [Security option benefits (Line 101)](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/rtrn/cmpltng/rprtng-ncm/lns101-170/101/scrty-eng.html) and [Security options deductions (Line 249)](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/rtrn/cmpltng/ddctns/lns248-260/249/menu-eng.html).  The distinction between a regular capital gain and an employee stock option benefits is *important*.  In many cases the net effect may be the same as a capital gain, but the income is characterized differently and there are cases where **it matters.**  Somebody who is about to or has realized employee stock option benefits should *seek professional tax advice*.

In response to your next two points:

- **No**, one cannot transfer a capital gain or other investment income into a TFSA immediately after-the-fact in order to receive the tax-free benefits of the TFSA on that income.  *Only* income and gains earned *within* a TFSA are free from tax – i.e. The options would have to have been in the TFSA before being exercised.  Once a gain or other investment income has been realized in a non-sheltered account, it is considered taxable.  The horse has already left the barn, so to speak!
- However, despite the above, there is another strategy available:  One can create an **offsetting deduction** by contributing some of the realized gain into an **RRSP**.  The RRSP contribution, assuming room is available, would yield a tax deduction to offset some tax due on the gain.  However, the RRSP only *defers* income tax; upon withdrawal of funds, ordinary income tax is due (hopefully, at a lower marginal rate in retirement.)
- There is no minimum amount of time that money or assets have to be inside a TFSA to benefit from the tax-free nature of the account.  However, [there are limits](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/tfsa-celi/cntrbtn-eng.html) on how much money you can move into a TFSA in any given year, and [many folks weren't aware of the rules](http://www.ellenroseman.com/?p=1022).

p.s. Let me add once more that this is a case where I suggest *seeking professional tax advice.*

Comment: You sir, are a godsend! Thank you very much for this valuable information and I will more than likely seek professional tax advice. Still, I can't thank you enough for answering this AND putting it in an easy-to-grasp fashion, I especially like the "horse has already left the barn" metaphor :D

Comment: @bigp You're welcome.  I'm happy to have helped.